# Dividend history from Yahoo finance

Tags: c++, api, yahoo-finance

Is there a convenient way to obtain dividend history for a specified company from the Yahoo finance API? For example, the historic data can be obtained by the following link, with some variable conditions

`https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/code_name?period1=from&period2=to&interval=1d&events=history`

Which, with those conditions filled, would look like:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/CBA.AX?period1=0&period2=1625841418&interval=1d&events=history

Which gives the data as `Date Open High Low Close AdjClose Volume`. What I would like to obtain is this, but for dividends. I.e. `Date Amount` in a specified period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the past dividends for, say Apple, using this query

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=from&period2=to&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true

To get the csv file, use this for Apple

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=From&period2=To&interval=1d&events=div&includeAdjustedClose=true

Try this for the dividends during last year again using Apple as an example

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1594598400&period2=1626134400&interval=1d&events=div&includeAdjustedClose=true

Comment: That doesn't download me a `csv` file that I can load into my C++ program. From the link in the question, it downloads the data in that format, is there a way to get the same outcome but for dividends via this way?

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb Added the download link for csv file using Apple as the company.

Comment: It doesn't retrieve any data when I run something such as https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/CBA.AX?946731600=From&1626188651=To&interval=1d&events=div&includeAdjustedClose=true there is no data.

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb I added an explicit download for dividends over the last year.

Comment: It is interesting that the csv isn't sorted by date for companies on the ASX, if you try https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/CBA.AX?period1=946731600&period2=1626134400&interval=1d&events=div&includeAdjustedClose=true (which is CBA.AX from 2000 till now)  they aren't sorted by any order. Anyway, that worked awesomly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Btw, what I was doing wrong when It didn't retrieve any data was change "period1" to a timestamp instead of "from"

Answer (score 0):

You can use R to get dividend information quite easily.
If you want the information from Yahoo then use `quantmod` library. The function to use is `getDividends("CBA.AX")`

```
library(quantmod)
getDividends("CBA.AX")
```

Comment: I edited the question, it needs to be done via C++, because I am trying to update a database. The program to do this is written in C++ and I can use CURL to obtain the data if it were from a link. The data comes from online and CURL allows the interface of loading the data into the program quite easy. The way to obtain it though, is from a link which I was hoping there would be some equivalent way but for dividends.